# Google Developer API, getting reviews of some apps

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-developers-console

I would like to create an app that shows the reviews of any application in the Google Play store, using the appId.

Is it possible to fetch all the reviews from any app in the store using the following API? Or this API allows getting only the reviews from my own apps?

[[Documentation of the API HERE]](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list)

[https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/reviews](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list)